# DHCP Option query

Tags: network-programming, windows-server-2008, d, dhcp

I have been looking around and have been trying to figure out how to query the dhcp server I am connected to and get all options available or to at least be able to query with a proper option in mind and get that information in response. Ideally getting all option information from the lease would be great but I really only need it for a specific option that I want to use to package/receive information with.

I have been looking at this in hopes to figure out how to alter it but I am not all that familiar with the D language, making it a cumbersome task. http://blog.thecybershadow.net/2013/01/10/dhcp-test-client/

**CODE:**

```
module dhcptest;

import core.thread;

import std.algorithm;
import std.array;
import std.conv;
import std.random;
import std.stdio;
import std.string;
import std.socket;

version(Windows)
    import std.c.windows.winsock : ntohs, htons, ntohl, htonl;
else
version(Posix)
    import core.sys.posix.netdb  : ntohs, htons, ntohl, htonl;
else
    static assert(false, "Unsupported platform");

/// Header (part up to the option fields) of a DHCP packet, as on wire.
align(1)
struct DHCPHeader
{
align(1):
    /// Message op code / message type. 1 = BOOTREQUEST, 2 = BOOTREPLY
    ubyte op;

    /// Hardware address type, see ARP section in "Assigned Numbers" RFC; e.g., '1' = 10mb ethernet.
    ubyte htype;

    /// Hardware address length (e.g.  '6' for 10mb ethernet).
    ubyte hlen;

    /// Client sets to zero, optionally used by relay agents when booting via a relay agent.
    ubyte hops;

    /// Transaction ID, a random number chosen by the client, used by the client and server to associate messages and responses between a client and a server.
    uint xid;

    /// Filled in by client, seconds elapsed since client began address acquisition or renewal process.
    ushort secs;

    /// Flags. (Only the BROADCAST flag is defined.)
    ushort flags;

    /// Client IP address; only filled in if client is in BOUND, RENEW or REBINDING state and can respond to ARP requests.
    uint ciaddr;

    /// 'your' (client) IP address.
    uint yiaddr;

    /// IP address of next server to use in bootstrap; returned in DHCPOFFER, DHCPACK by server.
    uint siaddr;

    /// Relay agent IP address, used in booting via a relay agent.
    uint giaddr;

    /// Client hardware address.
    ubyte[16] chaddr;

    /// Optional server host name, null terminated string.
    char[64] sname = 0;

    /// Boot file name, null terminated string; "generic" name or null in DHCPDISCOVER, fully qualified directory-path name in DHCPOFFER.
    char[128] file = 0;

    /// Optional parameters field.  See the options documents for a list of defined options.
    ubyte[0] options;

    static assert(DHCPHeader.sizeof == 236);
}

/*
35 01 02 
0F 17 68 6F 6D 65 2E 74 68 65 63 79 62 65 72 73 68 61 64 6F 77 2E 6E 65 74 
01 04 FF FF FF 00 
06 04 C0 A8 00 01 
03 04 C0 A8 00 01 
05 04 C0 A8 00 01 
36 04 C0 A8 00 01 
33 04 00 00 8C A0 
FF
*/

struct DHCPOption
{
    ubyte type;
    ubyte[] data;
}

struct DHCPPacket
{
    DHCPHeader header;
    DHCPOption[] options;
}

enum DHCPOptionType : ubyte
{
    subnetMask = 1,
    timeOffset = 2,
    router = 3,
    timeServer = 4,
    nameServer = 5,
    domainNameServer = 6,
    domainName = 15,
    leaseTime = 51,
    netbiosNodeType = 46,
    dhcpMessageType = 53,
    serverIdentifier = 54,
    renewalTime = 58,
    rebindingTime = 59,
}

enum DHCPMessageType : ubyte
{
    discover = 1,
    offer ,
    request ,
    decline ,
    ack ,
    nak ,
    release,
    inform
}

enum NETBIOSNodeType : ubyte
{
    bNode = 1,
    pNode,
    mMode,
    hNode
}

DHCPPacket parsePacket(ubyte[] data)
{
    DHCPPacket result;

    enforce(data.length > DHCPHeader.sizeof + 4, "DHCP packet too small");
    result.header = *cast(DHCPHeader*)data.ptr;
    data = data[DHCPHeader.sizeof..$];

    enforce(data[0..4] == [99, 130, 83, 99], "Absent DHCP option magic cookie");
    data = data[4..$];

    ubyte readByte()
    {
        enforce(data.length, "Unexpected end of packet");
        ubyte result = data[0];
        data = data[1..$];
        return result;
    }

    while (true)
    {
        auto optionType = readByte();
        if (optionType==0) // pad option
            continue;
        if (optionType==255) // end option
            break;

        auto len = readByte();
        DHCPOption option;
        option.type = optionType;
        foreach (n; 0..len)
            option.data ~= readByte();
        result.options ~= option;
    }

    return result;
}

ubyte[] serializePacket(DHCPPacket packet)
{
    ubyte[] data;
    data ~= cast(ubyte[])((&packet.header)[0..1]);
    data ~= [99, 130, 83, 99];
    foreach (option; packet.options)
    {
        data ~= option.type;
        data ~= to!ubyte(option.data.length);
        data ~= option.data;
    }
    data ~= 255;
    return data;
}

string ip(uint addr) { return format("%(%d.%)", cast(ubyte[])((&addr)[0..1])); }

void printPacket(DHCPPacket packet)
{
    auto opNames = [1:"BOOTREQUEST",2:"BOOTREPLY"];
    writefln(" op=%s\n chaddr=%(%02X:%)\n hops=%d\n xid=%08X\n secs=%d\n flags=%04X\n ciaddr=%s\n yiaddr=%s\n siaddr=%s\n giaddr=%s\n sname=%s\n file=%s",
        opNames.get(packet.header.op, text(packet.header.op)),
        packet.header.chaddr[0..packet.header.hlen],
        packet.header.hops,
        packet.header.xid,
        ntohs(packet.header.secs),
        ntohs(packet.header.flags),
        ip(packet.header.ciaddr),
        ip(packet.header.yiaddr),
        ip(packet.header.siaddr),
        ip(packet.header.giaddr),
        to!string(packet.header.sname.ptr),
        to!string(packet.header.file.ptr),
    );

    writefln("  %d options:", packet.options.length);
    foreach (option; packet.options)
    {
        auto type = cast(DHCPOptionType)option.type;
        writef("    %s: ", type);
        switch (type)
        {
            case DHCPOptionType.dhcpMessageType:
                enforce(option.data.length==1, "Bad dhcpMessageType data length");
                writeln(cast(DHCPMessageType)option.data[0]);
                break;
            case DHCPOptionType.netbiosNodeType:
                enforce(option.data.length==1, "Bad netbiosNodeType data length");
                writeln(cast(NETBIOSNodeType)option.data[0]);
                break;
            case DHCPOptionType.subnetMask:
            case DHCPOptionType.router:
            case DHCPOptionType.timeServer:
            case DHCPOptionType.nameServer:
            case DHCPOptionType.domainNameServer:
            case DHCPOptionType.serverIdentifier:
                enforce(option.data.length % 4 == 0, "Bad IP option data length");
                writefln("%(%s, %)", map!ip(cast(uint[])option.data).array());
                break;
            case DHCPOptionType.domainName:
                writeln(cast(string)option.data);
                break;
            case DHCPOptionType.timeOffset:
            case DHCPOptionType.leaseTime:
            case DHCPOptionType.renewalTime:
            case DHCPOptionType.rebindingTime:
                enforce(option.data.length % 4 == 0, "Bad integer option data length");
                writefln("%(%d, %)", map!ntohl(cast(uint[])option.data).array());
                break;
            default:
                writefln("%(%02X %)", option.data);
        }
    }
}

enum SERVER_PORT = 67;
enum CLIENT_PORT = 68;

__gshared UdpSocket socket;

void listenThread()
{
    try
    {
        static ubyte[0x10000] buf;
        ptrdiff_t received;
        Address address;
        while ((received = socket.receiveFrom(buf[], address)) > 0)
        {
            auto receivedData = buf[0..received].dup;
            try
            {
                auto packet = parsePacket(receivedData);
                writefln("Received packet from %s:", address);
                printPacket(packet);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
                writefln("Error while parsing packet [%(%02X %)]: %s", receivedData, e.toString());
        }

        throw new Exception(format("socket.receiveFrom returned %d.", received));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        writeln("Error on listening thread:");
        writeln(e.toString());
    }
}

void sendPacket()
{
    DHCPPacket packet;
    packet.header.op = 1; // BOOTREQUEST
    packet.header.htype = 1;
    packet.header.hlen = 6;
    packet.header.hops = 0;
    packet.header.xid = uniform!uint();
    packet.header.flags = htons(0x8000); // Set BROADCAST flag - required to be able to receive a reply to an imaginary hardware address
    foreach (ref b; packet.header.chaddr[0..packet.header.hlen])
        b = uniform!ubyte();
    packet.options ~= DHCPOption(DHCPOptionType.dhcpMessageType, [DHCPMessageType.discover]);
    writefln("Sending packet:");
    printPacket(packet);
    socket.sendTo(serializePacket(packet), new InternetAddress("255.255.255.255", SERVER_PORT));
}

void main()
{
    socket = new UdpSocket();
    socket.setOption(SocketOptionLevel.SOCKET, SocketOption.BROADCAST, 1);
    try
    {
        socket.setOption(SocketOptionLevel.SOCKET, SocketOption.REUSEADDR, 1);
        socket.bind(getAddress("0.0.0.0", CLIENT_PORT)[0]);
        writefln("Listening for DHCP replies on port %d.", CLIENT_PORT);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        writeln("Error while attempting to bind socket:");
        writeln(e);
        writeln("Replies will not be visible. Use a packet capture tool to see replies,\nor try re-running the program with more permissions.");
    }

    (new Thread(&listenThread)).start();

    writeln("Type \"d\" to broadcast a DHCP discover packet.");
    while (true)
    {
        auto line = readln().strip().split();
        if (!line.length)
        {
            writeln("Enter a command.");
            continue;
        }

        switch (line[0].toLower())
        {
            case "d":
            case "discover":
                sendPacket();
                break;
            default:
                writeln("Unrecognized command.");
        }
    }
}
```

From my understanding I will have to send a BOOTP vendor extension if I want to query for a specific option. I am not a networking guru and am looking for as much help as possible thank you.

**DHCP OPTIONS DOCUMENTATION:**
http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/bootp/options.htm

Comment: you should use `ubyte` instead `char` for ansii characters.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish (as in, what network-related problem are you trying to solve)? Your post isn't very specific. If you just want to see the lease time that your network's DHCP server offers, just send a "discover" packet by typing "d".

Comment: I am trying to accomplish querying the dhcp server on a specific option, say even 46 and to get back a response, or to get back and store the all dhcp options which have been presented/ see what options have been presented within the lease. There are a lot of ways to get the lease time, and all other things associated with the messageTypes I am trying to send with a specific option and get back a response if that clears things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need a one-off experiment, you can modify the `sendPacket` function to include the DHCP option you need. Notice the line:

```
packet.options ~= DHCPOption(DHCPOptionType.dhcpMessageType, [DHCPMessageType.discover]);
```

You can copy and edit it to add more options to the DHCP packet.

As for decoding, the program will already print all the data it receives, but it may not know how to decode every option. You may need to add more options to the respective enumerations, and to the switch statement that controls how these options are parsed and printed.